# Change color of a reference in bibliography

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, color

I am using `{thebibliography}` and I wanted to make one reference in blue font. I use `\color{blue}` but the problem is that the reference is in blue font but the number is still in black font.

Does anyone knows how to make the number blue as well?

I tried few things but couldn't manage. I tried something like `{\color{blue} \bibitem{ref2}}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I experience no problem getting both the bib entry and the associated number to show up in blue if either the `color` or the `xcolor` package is loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % or "color"

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ref1} faljadls;fjasl;fj

{\color{blue}
\bibitem{ref2} ldfja;lsfdj
}

\bibitem{ref3} ldfjas;dlfkja
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot. This help me to spot the mistake I did before.